# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in

Tags: php, mysqli

this is how I have to build the transmitters infomation on to a php file to send to login page when it is

```
<form action="http://,,,.dk/activate_updater.php" method="post" name="formular" onsubmit="return validerform ()">
                                 <table border="0">
                                     <tr>
                                         <td id="tb-w_a"><p>Kategori</p></td>
                                         <td>:</td>
                                         <td>
                                         <select name="kategori">
                                         <?php
                                         $query = "SELECT id_katogori, navn FROM kategori";
                                         $result = $mysqli->query($query);
                                         while(list($id_katogori, $navn) = $result->fetch_row())
                                         {
                                             echo "<option value=\"$id_katogori\">$navn</option>";  
                                         }
                                         ?>
                                         </select>
                                         </td>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                         <td id="tb-w_a"><p>Djnavn</p></td>
                                         <td>:</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="djnavn"></td>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                         <td id="tb-w_a"><p>Facebook</p></td>
                                         <td>:</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="facebook"></td>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                         <td id="tb-w_a"><p>Pris</p></td>
                                         <td>:</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="pris"></td>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                         <td id="tb-w_a"><p>Booking Email</p></td>
                                         <td>:</td>
                                         <td><input type="email" name="booking"></td>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                         <td id="tb-w_a"><p>Mobil</p></td>
                                         <td>:</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="mobil"></td>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                         <td id="tb-w_a"><p>Upload Profil</p></td>
                                         <td>:</td>
                                         <td><input type="file" name="profilbillede" /></td>
                                     </tr>
                                 </table>
                             <textarea name="profiltekst" style="width:500px; height:170px;"></textarea><br />
                             <input type="submit" value="Godkend brugere" name="godkendt-brugere">
                         </form>
```

so the new page file is like this where there are **errors** on the page ..

```
<?php
     if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE `brugere` SET `rank`=2, `katogori`=?, `djnavn`=?, `profilbillede`=?, `profiltekst`=?, `facebook`=?, `pris`=?, `booking`=?, `mobil`=? WHERE `code`=?'))
     {

         $stmt->bind_param('iiiiiiiis', $katogori, $djnavn, $profilbillede, $profiltekst, $facebook, $pris, $booking, $mobil, $g_code);
         //fra input ting ting..
         $katogori = $_POST["kategori"];
         $djnavn = $_POST["djnavn"];
         $profilbillede = $_POST["profilbillede"];
         $profiltekst = $_POST["profiltekst"];
         $facebook = $_POST["facebook"];
         $pris = $_POST["pris"];
         $booking = $_POST["booking"];
         $mobil = $_POST["mobil"];
         $g_code = $_GET["code"];

         $stmt->execute();
         $stmt->close();
         header('http://....dk/ (...));
     }
     else
     {
         echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklÃ¦ringen: ' . $mysqli->error;
     }
 ?>
```

but when it comes onto the file / page says it like this ...

**Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/jesperbo/public_html/....dk/activate_updater.php on line 2**

that is the where it says like this

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE `brugere` SET `rank`=2, `katogori`=?, `djnavn`=?, `profilbillede`=?, `profiltekst`=?, `facebook`=?, `pris`=?, `booking`=?, `mobil`=? WHERE `code`=?'))
```

*I'm not exactly the best person to see the error but it would be super if you had seen what I've needless churning wrong since it will not be up on the database*

**hope you can help me with this problem!**

Comment: Where are you initializing your `$mysqli` object? You are either not doing that or you have an error there.

Comment: I got the clear but now it will just not send me back or forward or what to say words to a new page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is happening because `$mysqli` isn't the object you think it is.** Either you didn't instantiate the `MySQLi` class properly, or it didn't make a connection. Do a `var_dump($mysqli)` to get more info as to what's going wrong.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can see, you never actually create your `$mysqli` object (unless it's loaded in another file, which includes this one). You need to [create it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php):

```
$mysqli = new MySQLi('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');

// then
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE `brugere` SET `rank`=2, `katogori`=?, `djnavn`=?, `profilbillede`=?, `profiltekst`=?, `facebook`=?, `pris`=?, `booking`=?, `mobil`=? WHERE `code`=?'))
```

Comment: Oh yes, now there is no error but there iMode send me on to the login page? hmm

Comment: @JesperPetersen If this problem has been fixed but you still have problems, you need to open another question.